# problem with hovering effect it not showing

Tags: html, css

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k1bkL.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kjam3.png)
So i'm trying to have a hover effect on my filter as shown on the html and css above but it not applying. However i have figured out that if i remove my "div pul" it works fine but on the other hand I need that div "pul" in order for my filters to be responsive on the mobile side, so if anyone have an other solution to offer it will be much appreciated. I have tried a number ways but nothing.

here is my website: https://mitch73.github.io/Reservia/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please edit yoru question to meet the SO guidelines. Provide a minimal reproducable code snippet (Ctrl + M) to show your issue. Providing an image as code is not acceptable. The source might change and besides of that it can be considered bad behavior. In order to reproduce the code, we would need to open that pciture and type your code from it while you simply could use copy & paste. Last but not least, provide more detail of what you already tried and what isnt working as intended. Your decription might be clear to you, but for others it is broad and vague.

Answer (score 1):

Your hover-css is applying.
Your problem is, the `a` element is an inline element and therefore margin-top is not applied to it.

here is a js-fiddle with your code:

https://jsfiddle.net/edwkaL1c/1/

Comment: that was indeed the problem thanks for the help much appreciated